# Radial and tangential velocities of a star

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, celestial-mechanics

[image]
([source](http://icc.dur.ac.uk/~tt/Lectures/Galaxies/TeX/lec/node42.html))

Early in this piece it states that the radial and tangential velocities are:

$$V_r = V_c \cos(\alpha) -V_{c,0} \sin (l)$$

$$V_t = V_c \sin(\alpha) -V_{c,0} \cos (l)$$

but I am struggling to see this. Surely the radial velocity will be related to $\sin (\alpha) $ and the tangential velocity to $\cos(\alpha )$?
I am also confused how the Sun's velocity and the galactic longitude are included.

Answer (score 1):

The radial velocity $V_r$ is the velocity resolved along the dashed line (the line of sight from the Sun to the star) *with respect to the Sun*. If $V_c$ is the velocity of the star, then the component along the dashed line is $V_c \cos (\alpha)$. We then have to *subtract* the velocity of the Sun resolved in the same direction. This is $V_{c,0} \sin (l)$.
Hence equation 1.

For the tangential velocities, do similar but resolved perpendicular to the dashed line, hence cosines change to sines and vice versa.